# Google app script random - Exception: Argument non valide : name - while naming renaming sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, invalid-argument

Hello and thanks for trying to help,

I am making a small code to copy some data from a spreadsheet to another specified one.
To arrange all the data in the new spreadsheet, I need to put it in different sheets, with references name.

The error occurs when a new sheet is created (by copy) and is going to be renamed.
This is working fine most of the time, but not always, which of course, is a problem.
It tells me the error is line 49 `tss.getSheets()[i].setName(ref[i]);`, and it is :

```
Exception: Invalid argument : name
```

This is strange because names are almost identical for all sheets, for example `S36779` is working, but `S36780` is not.

See below the code (it is not finished, but the sheet duplicate part is)

```
function onOpen(e) {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Fiche Produit')
      .addItem('Créer une fiche produit','creaficheproduit')
      .addSeparator()

      .addToUi();

}

function creaficheproduit() {

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = tss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length-1; i++) {
    tss.deleteSheet(sheets[i+1]);  
  } 
  var tsh = tss.getSheets()[0];

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var prompt = ui.prompt('Indiquer le lien de la Fiche CS source', 'lien',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL) 
  var response = prompt.getResponseText();
  var button = prompt.getSelectedButton();

  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {

    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(response);
    var ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Fiche_eclate_CS');

    var lrow = getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray (ssh,"D");
    var ref = ssh.getRange("D3:D"+lrow).getValues();

    var gamme = ssh.getRange(7,3).getValue();
    tsh.getRange(2,6).setValue(gamme);
    var dtotal = ssh.getRange(6,7).getValue();
    var htotal = ssh.getRange(7,7).getValue();
    var dAJ = ssh.getRange(9,7).getValue();
    var hAJ = ssh.getRange(10,7).getValue();
    tsh.getRange(4,7).setValue(dtotal + " - h" + htotal);
    tsh.getRange(5,7).setValue(dAJ + " - h" + hAJ);

    for (var i = 0; i < lrow; i++){
      if(i == 0){
        tss.getSheets()[0].setName(ref[i]);
        }
      else {
      tss.duplicateActiveSheet();
      tss.getSheets()[i].setName(ref[i]);
      }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lrow; i++){
      var sh = tss.getSheets()[i];
      sh.getRange(3,6).setValue(ref[i]);
    }

  }
  else{
  }

}

function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray(sheet,row) {
  
  var column = sheet.getRange(row + "3:" + row);
  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```

Feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: ref seems to be a 2d array here. What do you get when you log or inspect ref ? You probably need to get the element from the ref properly e.g. ref[i][j].

Comment: Try `String(ref[i][0])` instead.

Comment: I agree with the existing comments, ref[i] is an array. If that will not fix your issue, please provide a sample sheet for replication. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I tried to change with string `String(ref[i][0])`, but this is changing the problem to : "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". The one working before are still working, the one that was not working have the error.

Comment: @RonM sorry I can't share datas I need to put into those sheets. If you want to try the code, you can just put random data in range D3-Dxx in spreadsheet 1 and launch the code in spreadsheet 2 using spreadsheet's 1 URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake, it is a bad one...
In the `For` loop to duplicate and rename new sheet, I used :

```
  for (var i = 0; i < lrow; i++){
```

lrow is the row number of the last reference I need. This is not good because it is not equal to the array length, so it crashes.

Instead, I have to use ref.length, ref being the references array based on the lrow.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < ref.length; i++){
```

Thanks to all who answered.